# Как передаются сообщения между узлами в LAN(Ethernet)?

Tags: c#, сеть, сетевое-программирование

Помогите разобраться в таком нюансе: читаю сейчас литературу по сетевому програмированию(.NET) и буксую на моменте, где описана технология Ethernet(в частности передачи сообщений между узлами). В чем, собственно, вопрос:  на нижнем подуровне 2-го уровня модели OSI проживает MAC-адрес и протокол ARP. Возьмем вполне стандартную ситуацию, когда у нас есть, к примеру, локальная одноранговая ethernet сеть(через кабели, к примеру), и нужно от одного узла передать сообщение другому. И есть волшебное устройство коммутатор(одним из главных св-в которого, как я понял, является разрешение коллизий локалок через прямую адресацию, используя МАС-адрес). Так вот, я хочу с одного узла отправить сообщение другому узлу, будет ли при отправке сообщение в пакете данных указываться MAC-адрес(исходный и получателя) или там будут IP-адреса(исходный и получателя), которые после захода в сетевой адаптер узла через протокол ARP будут преобразовываться в MAC-адрес, сверяться и т.д.? Прошу поправить, если допустил где-то ошибку.

Comment: `читаю сейчас литературу по сетевому програмированию(.NET)` Какая взаимосвязь между `.NET`(C#) и сетевым программированием?

Comment: @ГеннадийП не понял вашего вопроса

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, будет, а как иначе? В пакете будут, и маки, и IP. За это отвечает ARP и таблица маршрутизации. Но MAC - это локомотив, который тянет ваш IP вагон, а на ближайшем узле локомотив прицепят другой, а вагон поедет дальше.

Когда вы что-то собираетесь сделать - у вас должен появиться конкретный вопрос. Когда вы что-то изучаете - у вас должна появиться конкретная гипотеза. Ни того не другого в вышеизложенном тексте я не увидел, а следовательно сделал вывод, что вы запутались, и вообще не поняли практически ничего про OSI. Попробуйте переизучить сначала.

Но я объясню на пальцах. Ethernet - это канальный уровень OSI передачи данных по локальной сети. Физический уровень OSI - это медный провод, Wi-Fi (к примеру 802.11n), передающий по радиоканалу, ну или множеству радиоканалов одновременно, кому как угодно, у оптики могут быть свои прибамбасы.

Так вот, MAC-адрес - это адрес физического сетевого устройства, так уж условились, что MAC адреса используются, и в мире меди, и оптики, и радио, но это условие для существования Интернета вовсе не обязательно, просто так получилось. Когда вы втыкаете медный провод, витую пару в компьютер одним концом, а в маршрутизатор другим - вы связываете 2 устройства по протоколу Ethernet, а чтобы они узнавали друг друга и не путались, они называют друг друга по имени - MAC адресу. В локальной сети, где все устройства могут видеть друг друга посредством коммутации, они видят эти адреса друг друга, при этом часть устройств могут быть подключены по Wi-Fi, часть по проводам, на канальном уровне Ethernet это не важно. Это и есть разница между физическим и канальным уровнями.

Но как только вам потребовался доступ в интернет, вы идете в магазин за маршрутизатором, потому что провайдер хочет отделить вашу локальную сеть от себя, и допускает подключение только одного устройства на физическом уровне, и вот здесь вступает в бой IP, и сама маршрутизация - сетевой уровень OSI.

Чтобы вам достучаться до устройства вне вашей локальной сети, вы отправляете пакет своему маршрутизатору с просьбой отправить его дальше, он делает то же самое, отправляя следующему маршрутизатору, и так далее. А так как IP, это стандарт сетевой адресации, а не протокол передачи данных, здесь вступает в бой TCP, и с IP они неразлучные друзья, поэтому и пишут TCP/IP. И рядом с TCP еще гуляет UDP. Это транспортный уровень OSI.

Далее на это все наращивается больше всякой всячины, которая уже способна гулять по всему интернету, я не буду про нее рассказывать. Успехов в освоении темы.

Кстати, а при чем здесь C#? Если кратко, то мир связи для C# начинается с уровня TCP/IP. Открывается сокет, улетает TCP пакет по IP адресу. Совершенно фиолетово, что там уровнями ниже. Вот и всё.

Comment: Большое спасибо за развернутый ответ

Comment: Позвольте уточнить: на канальном уровне(ethernet), узлы узнают друг друга исключительно по МАС-адресу устройства, а когда мы говорим уже про транспортный уровень, как вы сказали, здесь уже добавляются ip-адреса. И если узел локальной сети, после отправки пакета данных ждет ответ,  то этот ответ возвращается на маршрутизатор его локальной сети, далее по этой сети пакет(ip) данных заходит в каждый сетевой адаптер(там преобразуется ip в mac через ARP) и происходит сверка, если не этому узлу - идет дальше и т.д. до победного конца?

Comment: @IAMLERNCSHARP верно, до победного, или пока не кончится TTL

Comment: @IAMLERNCSHARP правда не совсем так, принятый пакет маршрутизатор уже заранее знает, какому устроуству в локальной сети отправить, то есть он видит IP, смотрит в свою таблицу ARP, достает из нее нужный MAC адрес, и отправляет пакет сразу приемнику по MAC адресу. Подробнее как это работает, описано [здесь](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARP)